# How to Determine JRE Path in MacOS

Tags: java, installation

can you please help. So I can't find my JRE path.

[JRE is installed if i check with java -version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0QA.png)

[JRE folder should be here /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7myG3.png)

But i got nothing. What should i do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So i found that jdk 12 doesnt have jre folder anymore. maybe this can help people.

Answer (score 1):

There is no JRE for Java 12, there never will be, there is only the JDK now.